# How to define an interface that accepts zero or more dynamically named attributes in Typescript

Tags: typescript, interface

I have an interface that looks like this:

```
export interface ReportingNodeConfig {
  template: string;
  dashboardName: string;
  dashboardDescription: string;
  reportUrlSelect: SelectProps.Option;
  platformSelect: SelectProps.Option;
}
```

What is the right pattern to enforce the interface I defined above while allowing additional dynamic attributes that match a certain type?

In other words, how can I define an interface to require that all attributes in it are present but also allow zero or more additional attributes of a certain type BUT dynamic key name.

Additional values might follow the pattern `[key: string]: string`

An actual object would look like this:

```
{
  template: "test",
  dashboardName: "foo",
  dashboardDescription: "bar"
  reportUrlSelect: "test1"
  platformSelect: "hello world",
  dynamicallyGeneratedAttr: "I might not always be here",
  anotherDynamicAttr: "I'm also not guaranteed to be here all the time"
}
```

I know I can extend the interface and have also read about [dynamic keys](https://www.vincecampanale.com/blog/2018/01/12/dynamically-properties-to-typescript-interfaces/) for interfaces but a dynamic key would not work in this case.

Thank you.

Comment: What is `SelectProps.Option`?  Please provide a [mre].  If `SelectProps.Option` is `string` or a subtype thereof, then you can just add the index signature to your interface directly like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wE5BZw).  But you say "a dynamic key would not work in this case".  Can you demonstrate that with code someone can just paste into a standalone IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge in an index signature:

```
type Foo = ReportingNodeConfig & { [key: string]: string | undefined }
```

Testing it:

```
declare const foo: Foo

foo.template // string
foo.reportUrlSelect // SelectProps.Option

if (foo.someUnknownPropHere) {
    foo.someUnknownPropHere // string here
}
```

You'll definitely want it to resolve to a union with `undefined`, though, because you can't be sure those properties ever actually exist when you look them up.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBlCAbC8AuAFATgPYxRIDeAUEtUhAB4yH7ZLYCeMyA8jNgJaFgSALzkkANxDoArhABcSKNnx9gAcyQBfCtoqrsEfADMEyAEoRGzVWoByhACYQAwoKN8NlagbAx0IAwUlFXUAbiokBxAoAAsAI0IQfAdbcHlFZRtw6ijYhKSHABFoeBVeAWAgzLCI-EsmbABVfHQ0TBwFNqw8IhIAOh5+QWykPwCjJjAujtQMboJiKAHy4Z0KCnZOJAAxQkIRJAsrfnV7J1dgdw0AMjEAbQBrCDYqkLUAXVebJAAfJGlgE53MAIA4tOsnPB-HUkPBBEokBNCApdoR1ki+j4xgYkAB6XEZN4UDF1Y7NVpzHB9SQyZD4wk2dZ8IxIAAUGKghEgjWAD2AhAA7sAFjAABKGCAASnIEWoHK5EB5fMFwt64ph9OC3xiEp0QA)

---

That said, if you can change this data model, then you probably should. If you have free form property names, then they are very likely to be a totally different type of data and should be stored in a nested object instead.

Like say:

```
export interface ReportingNodeConfig {
  template: string;
  dashboardName: string;
  dashboardDescription: string;
  reportUrlSelect: SelectProps.Option;
  platformSelect: SelectProps.Option;
  customData: Record<string, string | undefined>
}
```

Now you can cram whatever you want in `customData` without polluting the statically verifiable property names.

Comment: This ended up looking for me. Thank you. Next week I'll discuss with the team the possibility of changing the data model to allow a `customData` attribute to hold the elements with free form keys, make sure it doesn't break anything.

Answer (score 1):

### Record

`Record<Keys, Type>` constructs an object type whose property keys are Keys and whose property values are Type. This utility can be used to map the properties of a type to another type.

Better explained in [TS Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type).

### Solution

You may want to use `Record<string, string>`